# pie chart not rendered properly in flask app

Tags: python, chart.js, pdfkit

I would like to put pie chart on my html page and convert it to pdf by using both wkhtml2pdf and pdfkit tools in Flask app.But it can't happen properly .

It seems slices of chart is incomplete and proportions are being miscomputed.

[image: pie chart after rendering result:]

here is python side :

```
   html = render_template('chart3.html')
   pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False)
```

here is my simple chart3.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      // Global parameters:
      // do not resize the chart canvas when its container does (keep at 600x400px)
      Chart.defaults.global.responsive = false;

      // define the chart data
      var chartData = {
                    labels: [
                        'Chrome',
                        'IE',
                        'FireFox',
                        'Safari',
                        'Opera',
                        'Navigator',
                    ],
                    datasets: [
                      {
                        data: [700,500,400,600,300,100],
                        backgroundColor : ['#f56954', '#00a65a', '#f39c12', '#00c0ef', '#3c8dbc', '#d2d6de'],
                      }
                    ]
      }

      // get chart canvas
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

      var options = {
              tooltips: {
                enabled: false
              },
              plugins: {
                labels: [
                        {
                            render: 'label',
                            position: 'outside',
                            fontColor: '#000',
                            fontSize: 15
                        },
                        {
                            render: 'percentage',
                            fontColor: '#000',
                            fontSize: 10,
                            position: 'border',
                        }
                ]
               }
};

      // create the chart using the chart canvas
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: chartData,
          options:options
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried  many ways to find solution but couldn't find yet. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the capture has happened midway through the animation.  Try disabling animantion in your `options` object:

```
var options = {
    animation: false,

    // ...
    }
```